# remind: Undefined variable

Tags: linux, reminder

Following entry in ~/.reminders (used by [remind](https://linux.die.net/man/1/remind)) causes `Undefined variable: EXT` to be displayed:

```
REM Oct 1 2019 AT 17:30 +15 DURATION 1:0 MSG %"Fw: [EXT] some title body%" [t()]
```

Is there an automatic way to escape the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in the [mailing list archive](https://dianne.skoll.ca/pipermail/remind-fans/2018/003489.html):

```
REM Oct 1 2019 AT 17:30 +15 DURATION 1:0 MSG %"Fw: ["["]EXT["]"] some title body%" [t()]
```

Or as described later in the message. Set variable and use it instead.

```
# set variable EXT containing string [EXT]
SET EXT "[EXT]"
# use variable EXT -> expand variable EXT to string [EXT]
REM Oct 1 2019 AT 17:30 +15 DURATION 1:0 MSG %"Fw: [EXT] some title body%" [t()]
```

Another option I've just discovered is using `char()` function:

````
REM Oct 1 2019 AT 17:30 +15 DURATION 1:0 MSG %"Fw: [char(91)]EXT[char(93)] some title body%" [t()]```
````